# WebForms ReportViewer control error. "Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'."

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am trying to test load an SSRS report from a server hosting the reports in the browser from a .cshtml file by redirecting it to an .aspx file that contains a ReportViewer control when a button is clicked.

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

In the backend of the .aspx file, I added the following:

```
 ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
 IReportServerCredentials irsc = new ReportServerCredentials("username", "password", "domain");
 ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
 ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://domain/ReportServer/ReportViewer.aspx");
 ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report/path";
 ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] {
     new ReportParameter("param1", "sample1"),
     new ReportParameter("param2", "sample2")
 });
 ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

The 'ReportServerCredentials' class is a class imeplementing IReportServerCredentials.

I tried using a browser to connect to the specified domain with the username and password and viewing the report in the specified 'ReportPath', and verified that I could successfully access and view the report.

However, when the program runs and hits this method:

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameter
```

this error occur:

```
Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.
```

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Try changing the URL by adding question mark (`?`) after extension like this: `ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://domain/ReportServer/ReportViewer.aspx?");`.

Comment: I tried adding `?` and removing `/` in ReportPath, doesn't help.

Comment: I'm not tell you to change `ReportPath` - are you tried suggested `ReportServerUrl` already? Also try setting `ContentType` to `text/xml` if such setting exists, since the report data expects XML format but received null or empty instead.

Comment: My bad. I should not combine the words in the same sentence.
Yes, I tried already on the `?` in the `ReportServerUrl`. I also tried adding and removing `/` from the `ReportPath`, just in case, but still same result.
By default it is already expecting text/xml, but I also tried adding the content type, still same result.

Comment: I tested changing the `ReportPath` to point to an inexistent report, and it gave the same error as the above. I believe it could not find my report for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

The error was actually telling me that the `ReportServerUrl` was wrong. In my case, instead of

```
http://domain/ReportServer/ReportViewer.aspx?
```

I should actually use

```
http://domain/ReportServer
```

The error disappeared after that because it was able to connect to the report. However, nothing shows up because of an issue with the .aspx file. The UI contents of the file was not being loaded into the page, which led to the page being empty.